# Reg rejection boundary valued test statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

In my hypothesis test, under H0, if I get the p-value for the test statistic as exactly 5%(please assume), then should I reject H0 or fail to reject H0. Test carried out at 5% level significance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's completely up to you.  There is no (valid) rule that says you should always use 5%, and likewise there is no rule that says whether you should put 5% on one side or the other of the decision.  The circumstances where this matters are where *somebody else* supplies the decision criterion (such as a government regulator).  If you're in such a position, then please edit your post to explain what the criterion is (at which point you will have answered your own question).

Comment: Hi Whuber, I am just a student of statistics and had this doubt when going through the notes. We generally use 5% significance tests for most of our theoretic practice problems. I was just concerned since the rejection region interval is not specified as open or closed (containing the critical value) in my books.